# asp.net MVC4 Access to a variable from a view in another view (ActionLink)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, view, actionlink

i have the following problem with my Forestry Management Applpication:

**Index.cshtml:**

```
@model IEnumerable<ForestryManagement.Models.Forestry>

 @foreach (var forestry in Model)
    {
        <li>@Html.ActionLink(forestry.Name, "Index12", new {tree = forestry.ForestryID})


    }
```

When you click on one Forestry (ActionLink), you will be redirected to the Index12, where the trees from these Forestry are listed

**Index12.cshtml:**

```
@model IEnumerable<ForestryManagement.Models.Tree>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>


        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.treeName)

        </td>
        </tr>

@Html.ActionLink("Create new Tree", "Create", new { id = **??????**}) //need ForestyID from Index.cshtml here
```

Now, when i will create another tree in this forestry, i need the ID from the forestry on my Index12.cshtml page for the ActioLink

Comment: You need to use view models - not pass your data entities to your views - and put the ID in the model for each view. http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-3

Answer (score 0):

Create a view model for tree listings, like so:

```
public class TreeListingViewModel
{
    public int ForestryId { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<TreeViewModel> Trees { get; set; }
}
```

Note: Prefer creating a `TreeViewModel` instead of just using your `Tree` data entity to reduce the dependency between your view and your data model (and also increase security as people can quite easily inject properties into your database if you expose your data entities directly to your view).

Pass that to your view instead:

```
@model TreeListingViewModel

...

@Html.ActionLink("Create new Tree", "Create", new { id = Model.ForestryId })
```